# Strange RAM behavior in Kingfisher

Tags: ios, swift, caching, ram, kingfisher

I use Kingfisher to load images into the Card View (`UIView`), as in the tinder, I set the Kingfisher to cache the images to disk, but during the paging of the cards, the memory consumption increases dramatically from 39 megabytes to 247 and after a while again becomes 39, But the problem is that when the memory is freed, in the application for a second UI slows down (I think this is blocked by the main thread). This problem is similar to [this one.](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher/issues/686) How can I fix it?

I set the settings for Kingfisher in `AppDelegate` in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
fileprivate func setupKingfisherSettings() {
        let megabytes: UInt = 300
        ImageCache.default.maxDiskCacheSize = megabytes * 1024 * 1024
        ImageCache.default.maxMemoryCost = 1
    }
```

Snippet of code. When I removed this code, this problem did not occur.

```
private func downloadImages(_ card: CardModel) {
    if let placeAvatarURLString = card.photoURLsProperties.placePhotoURLs.first {
        if let placeAvatarURL = URL(string: placeAvatarURLString) {
            venueImageView.kf.indicatorType = .activity
            venueImageView.kf.setImage(with: placeAvatarURL)
        } else {
            venueImageView.image = UIImage(named: "CardDefaultImage")
        }
    } else if let eventLogoURLPath = card.photoURLsProperties.placeLogoURLs.first {
        if let url = URL(string: eventLogoURLPath) {
            venueImageView.kf.indicatorType = .activity
            venueImageView.kf.setImage(with: url)
        } else {
            venueImageView.image = UIImage(named: "CardDefaultImage")
        }
    } else {
        venueImageView.image = UIImage(named: "CardDefaultImage")
    }
}
```

[image]

**Updated:**: I found a regularity when this happens. This jump in memory occurs when ImageCache extracts an image that is larger than 5 megabytes. I found it using debugPrint in this method diskImage, if the image is equal to or more than 5 megabytes, then there is a jump, if 4 megabytes, then everything is fine.

I'm testing on the iPhone 7, more than 74 gigabytes of free memory.

```
 func diskImage(forComputedKey key: String, serializer: CacheSerializer, options: KingfisherOptionsInfo) -> Image? {
        if let data = diskImageData(forComputedKey: key) {
            debugPrint("ImageCache data.count", data.count / 1024 / 1024)
            return serializer.image(with: data, options: options)
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please provide code snip too, I did encounter same memory issue with kingfisher and posted issue on Kingfisher. Seems there is some issue that needs to be fixed, Finally i switched to SDWebImage.

Comment: @dip Also I want to say that I published this issue in the Kingfisher issue

Comment: @dip My issue https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher/issues/703

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment I solved my problem, I wrote my Custom CacheSerializer, and I compress the images up to 3 megabytes. But I'm interested in other answers, how to solve this problem.

```
import Kingfisher

struct AppNameKingfisherCacheSerializer: CacheSerializer {

    func data(with image: Image, original: Data?) -> Data? {
        return image.compressToData(3)
    }

    func image(with data: Data, options: KingfisherOptionsInfo?) -> Image? {
        return UIImage(data: data)
    }

}
```